# Use generic type and cast to other class type in Swift

Tags: swift

I am a new iOS developer. Based on my experience in android development, I am trying to write api class, request and auto parse json based on type input use HandyJSON library, something like

```
static func request<T: NSObject>(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, doOnSuccess: @escaping (T)-> Void, doOnError: @escaping (Error)-> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response
        in
            if (T is BaseResponse) {  // This is Invalid Swift code

                // I am using HandyJSON Library to parse to T
                if let jsonObject = (T as! BaseResponse).deserialize(from: response.result.value as? NSDictionary) {
                    doOnSuccess(jsonObject)
                }
            }
            else {
                doOnError(NSError.init(domain: APIRouter.DOMAIN, code: APIRouter.ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, userInfo: nil))
            }
        }
    })
}
```

There're part in this code are invalid in Swift and I couldn't search any solution for that.

Also it's welcome if you have any suggestion for my api request function. I'm so surprise that in my project, they don't parse json and access value based on key, also use some json parser library like HandyJSON is not popular.

Comment: You should read about [`Codable`](https://medium.com/xcblog/painless-json-parsing-with-swift-codable-2c0beaeb21c1)

Comment: change `request<T: NSObject>` to `request<T: BaseResponse >` and remove the if condition and casting to `BaseResponse` while deserializing

Comment: @Mukesh yes but sometime response is array, so I want to pass it as any object. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create Generic method which can return `BaseResponse` and also `Array< BaseResponse >` then you should create two methods like:

```
static func request<T: BaseResponse>(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, doOnSuccess: @escaping (T)-> Void, doOnError: @escaping (Error)-> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response
        in
            if let jsonObject = T.deserialize(from: response.result.value as? NSDictionary) {
                doOnSuccess(jsonObject)
            } else {
                doOnError(NSError.init(domain: APIRouter.DOMAIN, code: APIRouter.ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, userInfo: nil))
            }
    })
}

static func request<T: BaseResponse>(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, doOnSuccess: @escaping ([T])-> Void, doOnError: @escaping (Error)-> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response
        in
            if let jsonObject = [T].deserialize(from: response.result.value as? NSDictionary) {
                doOnSuccess(jsonObject)
            } else {
                doOnError(NSError.init(domain: APIRouter.DOMAIN, code: APIRouter.ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, userInfo: nil))
            }
    })
}
```

You can also move the `Alamofire` code to a different method and return `Dictionary` from it and do the parsing in individual methods.